# Realm access inside Rx Observable error

Tags: android, rx-java, realm

I'm getting error when i try to make operation on realm instance as like below:

```
.flatMap(h -> Observable.from(h.getEntityDataList())).filter(p -> p.isMyProfile())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<ProfileView>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.v("test", "error: " + e.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ProfileView profileView) {                        
                    realmManager.saveActiveUser(gson.toJson(profileView));
                   //...
                }
            });
```

RealmManager:

```
public class RealmManager{
    private Realm realm;

    public RealmManager(){
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    public void saveActiveUser(String json)}{
        realm...
    }
```

Code enters to `onError()` above showing `realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created`. I am injecting `RealmManager` into first code with Dagger.

How to overcome this ? And what is the best practice to make RealmManager class? Should i make RealmManager singleton (and realm object static) and access it everywhere? Should i make it like above and  inject it whenever i want?

**EDIT:** i'm injecting RealmManager instance which is provided in Application Component which is Singleton.

Comment: @christian-melchior any thoughts

Answer (score 2):

Due to Realm-objects are live objects you can not get it on one thread (IO-thread) and use in another (main-thread). You could detach these objects by using next code (took from Realm's documentation):

```
realm.where(Person.class).findFirst().<Person>asObservable()
    .map(new Func1<Person, Person>() {
        @Override
        public Person call(Person person) {
            // Convert live object to a static copy
            return realm.copyFromRealm(person);
        }
    })
    .buffer(2)
    .subscribe(new Action1<List<Person>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(List<Person> persons) {
            // Without `map` and `copyFromRealm`, v1 and v2 would be the same
            Person v1 = persons.get(0);
            Person v2 = persons.get(1);
        }
    });
```

Using Realm with Dagger is not so smooth as I want.

You should not forget to close Realm. Otherwise your app will be more likely get killed by the system (in case of low resources).

`Realm.getInstance()` creates instance for each thread. And you can't create Realm in one thread and use it in another.

I thing the best choice is using DI's scopes. But as a quick solution you could try `Provider<Realm> realmProvider` construction in dagger's module.

Comment: So on each Dagger Module, i should provide new Realm.getInstance() ?

Comment: And problem i have is not related to live object (like Person..), but `realm` object itself i think.

Comment: Not module, you should get Realm via Realm.getInstance() on each thread where you are going to use it

Comment: Well since above code does not directly @Inject realmManager, but takes it as parameter since RealmManager is provided on same component, i can not use Provider<T> i guess

Comment: maybe not using Dagger is best solution, however creating Realm.getDefaultInstace() in every class sounds not good